# Get window position after drag it

Tags: gtk, drag, vala

I want get the window position after drag it.

Here is my code:

```
    button_press_event.connect ((e) => {
            if(e.button == 1){
                    begin_move_drag ((int)e.button, (int)e.x_root, (int)e.y_root, e.time);
            } else {Gtk.main_quit();}
            return true;
    });
    button_release_event.connect ((e) => {
         get_position(out rootx, out rooty);
         stdout.printf("root: %d x %d\n",rootx,rooty);
            return true;
    });
```

If I called `begin_move_drag`, I found `button_release_event` become invalid.

I've seen some articles mention about using `GLib.Timeout` to wait it. But that not fit my requires, for some actions would be occurred immediatlly after drag finished.

Any advise?